# is it gerund or participle?

Tags: present-participles, ing, gerund-phrases

> Seeing the tiger, the man ran away.

I'd like to know whether 'seeing' is gerund or participle? may be explained.

Comment: In 'Seeing the tiger, the man ran away' 'seeing the tiger' describes an event happening. This is a verbal usage; the -ing form is the participle. In 'Seeing the tiger proved impossible because of the dense jungle', 'seeing the tiger' is behaving far more like a noun, both in role ('**observation** of the tiger proved impossible') and grammatical function (**seeing the tiger** is the subject).

Answer (score 2):

It is a **participle**. A participle functions (externally) like an adjective; the word *seeing* describes and modifies *the man* in your example, so it is a participle.

Separating the participle from the noun it modifies by a comma, as in your example, is called *apposition*.

A gerund functions like a noun; if it were a gerund, then it would be hanging in the air in your example. You can test this by replacing it with a somewhat similar noun:

> <s>The action of seeing the tiger, the man ran away.</s>

This doesn't work. (And don't add prepositions before the gerund to make it work: that's cheating!)

> Tiger-aware, the man ran away.

As you see, it works if you replace it with an adjective, so it is a participle.

Answer (score 0):

This participle construction is a shortening for a clause with when/as.

1 - When/as he saw the tiger, the man ran away.

2 - when seeing the tiger, ...

3 - Seeing the tiger, ...

Temporal or causal clauses can be shortened by using participle constructions. Occasionally other kinds of clauses, too.

Comment: *Upon seeing the tiger*: this is a gerundial construction, but it can just as easily be converted into a conjunctive construction such as your *when seeing the tiger*. I don't think this kind of conversion proves much?

Comment: @Cerberus -  Do you really think "The seeing of the tiger +  the man ran away" go together?

Comment: By adding "upon"  you change the first part to a gerund construction. But generally such a sentence part  is seen as an adverbial clause shortened by means of a participle construction. This is frequent with adverbial clauses of time (when/as/while), of manner/circumstance and  of cause. Sometimes you even find conjunctions with participle constructions.

Comment: With all due respect, but I think you missed my point. You converted a participial construction into a *when seeing* construction. I converted a gerundial construction into exactly the same. So you can convert either construction into a *when seeing* construction, which means that the conversion cannot be used to prove anything. Agreed? (What is more, the participial construction isn't really a shortening of anything: it's just a different construction. But I don't think you meant that "shortening" literally.)